# How to determine if parallel arrays categorized based on the other?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

Sorry for the title. I'll try to be thorough and clear as I can. I have an assignment on c programming based on parallel arrays. Here what I understood so far. The assignment is about storm information,  that is categorized based on a scale of hurricane. The hurricane function reads a 5x3 array (5 rows & 3 columns) from an input file and store it in a three separate arrays. Similarly, the storm function reads a 10x2 array (10 rows & 2 columns) from an input file and store it in two separate arrays. Now having said all of that, I done all of these parts. My issue is that I have to determine if the storm information is categorized as hurricane or not. The storm information include identification number and wind speed. The hurricane scale include catogory number, mi wind speed, and max wind speed. Once I determine this, I need to output the storm identification number, the storm peak wind, and the hurricane catogory number. I know this involves in if statements. However, I can't seem to figure it out. I thought to declare two variables and assign them to the two functions, but I don't where to go from there. Sorry if my question is long. I'm just stuck is all. Below is a copy of my code.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SizeHurrRows 5
#define SizeHurrCols 3

#define SizeStormRows 10
#define SizeStormCols 3

#define IN_FILE_NAME1  "categoryInfo.txt"
#define IN_FILE_NAME2  "storms.txt"


void readCategoryInfo(FILE *fin1, float ArrayHurr1[][SizeHurrCols], float ArrayHurr2[][SizeHurrCols],
                                  float ArrayHurr3[][SizeHurrCols]);

void readStormInfo(FILE *fin2, float ArrayStorm1[][SizeStormCols], float ArrayStorm2[][SizeStormCols]);

void processStorms(float ArrayHurr1 [][SizeHurrCols ], float ArrayHurr2 [][SizeHurrCols ],
                   float ArrayHurr3 [][SizeHurrCols ], float ArrayStorm1[][SizeStormCols],
                   float ArrayStorm2[][SizeStormCols]);

void printHeader();

int main()
{

    float ArrayHurr1[SizeHurrRows][SizeHurrCols], ArrayHurr2[SizeHurrRows][SizeHurrCols],
          ArrayHurr3[SizeHurrRows][SizeHurrCols];

    float ArrayStorm1[SizeStormRows][SizeStormCols], ArrayStorm2[SizeStormRows][SizeStormCols];

    float *fin1 = NULL;
    float *fin2 = NULL;


    readCategoryInfo(fin1, ArrayHurr1, ArrayHurr2, ArrayHurr3);
    readStormInfo(fin2, ArrayStorm1, ArrayStorm2);
    printHeader();

    processStorms(ArrayHurr1, ArrayHurr2, ArrayHurr3, ArrayStorm1, ArrayStorm2);





    return 0;
}

/********************************************

 This function reads the hurricane information file into three seperate arrays.

 Input parameter: fin2, ArrayHurr1, ArrayHurr2, ArrayHurr3.

 Return: This function doesn't return anything.

 *******************************************/

void readCategoryInfo(FILE *fin1, float ArrayHurr1[][SizeHurrCols], float ArrayHurr2[][SizeHurrCols],
                      float ArrayHurr3[][SizeHurrCols])
{

    fin1 = fopen(IN_FILE_NAME1, "r");
    if (fin1 == NULL)
    {
        printf( "Error occurred reading input file!  Exit...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("\nOpened the file successfully!\n");

    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < SizeHurrRows; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < SizeHurrCols; j++)
        {
            fscanf(IN_FILE_NAME1, "%f%f%f", &ArrayHurr1[i][j], &ArrayHurr2[i][j], &ArrayHurr3[i][j])
        }
    }
    fclose(fin1);
}

/********************************************

 This function reads the storm info file into two seperate arrays.

 Input parameter: fin2, ArrayStorm1, ArrayStorm2.

 Return: This function doesn't return anything.

 *******************************************/

void readStormInfo(FILE *fin2, float ArrayStorm1[][SizeStormCols], float ArrayStorm2[][SizeStormCols])
{

    fin1 = fopen(IN_FILE_NAME2, "r");
    if (fin2 == NULL)
    {
        printf( "Error occurred reading input file!  Exit...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("\nOpened the file successfully!\n");

    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < SizeStormRows; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < SizeStormCols; j++)
        {
            fscanf(IN_FILE_NAME2, "%f%f", &ArrayStorm1[i][j], &ArrayStorm2[i][j])
        }
    }
    fclose(fin2);
}

/********************************************

 This function process the storms information and catogrized it based on the hurricane catogory.

 Input parameter: ArrayHurr1, ArrayHurr2, ArrayHurr3, ArrayStorm1, ArrayStorm2.

 Return: This function doesn't return anything.

 *******************************************/

void processStorms(float ArrayHurr1 [][SizeHurrCols ], float ArrayHurr2 [][SizeHurrCols ],
                   float ArrayHurr3 [][SizeHurrCols ], float ArrayStorm1[][SizeStormCols],
                   float ArrayStorm2[][SizeStormCols]);
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;



    for ( ; i < SizeHurr ; i++)
    {
        for ( ; j < SizeStorm ; j++)
        {
            printf("\n-15%f %-15f %-15f", readCategoryInfo[i][j], readStormInfo[i][j]);
        }
    }









}

/********************************************

 This function prints out the header of the table. 

 Input parameter: None.

 Return: This function doesn't return anything.

 *******************************************/

void printHeader()
{
    printf("\nStorms that Qualify as Hurricanes");
    printf("\n---------------------------------------------------------");
    printf("\nIdentification      Peak Wind (mph)      Category");
    printf("\n---------------------------------------------------------");
}
```

Comment: Why do you pass `fin1` and `fin2` to the functions reading the files, why not declare the `FILE*` variables locally in the functions? And why do you declare `fin1` and `fin2` as `float*` in the `main` function?

Comment: Because that's how we do it in class and we're required to do so. Also, it's required to declare fin1 and fin2 as floating points to a null terminator in main.

Comment: I'm so sorry that was a typo, I should have wrote FILE* instead of float*. Also, when we started learning reading files, we were required to delclere the FILE* in main, so I assumed by default that I would have to do the same here. Sorry again.

Comment: Okay, and I'm sorry for sounding harsh. When you started programming and learning reading files, you probably did it *in* the `main` function, which is why you defined the `FILE*` variable there. As a rule of thumb, you should have variables as close to where they are used as possible. If you use a variable in one function and one function only, then it should be defined as a local variable in that function.

Comment: That's alright you're fine. Yes thats how we started learning them. Thanks for the tip, it helps in the future.

Comment: Could you help with question?